# Logging user access in SSAS and Powerpivot

Tags: ssas

Is there anyone who has an idea how i can log user access in SSAS and Power Pivot?
The problem we face that we need to keep track of who is accessing what. it is not enough to save the question when the result set changes over time (SELECT * ... does not result in the same today as yesterday), so the whole or parts result set need to be logged. I can imagine that it is possible to solve for reports created in SSAS, as it is being in a SQL server. Power Pivot and self-service BI, I'm more thoughtful about how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

If your Power Pivots are stored in a BI-enabled SharePoint site then those Power Pivot workbooks are effectively on a regular SSAS tabular server also. So any logging that you can put in place for an SSAS tabular database you could probably adapt for PowerPivot workbooks. But in the SharePoint SQL Server instance you will also find a database called DefaultPowerPivotServiceApplication[GUID]. In this database you will have a table called [Usage].[Requests] that records who access what file and when.